# Images taking a while to load every time I start

Tags: react-native, expo

Can anyone tell me why when I use my app, every boot up has a lag when loading my images and vector font icons? It probably only lags for a second, but it looks really bad.

It can't be the sizes of them because even the vector icons have about a second lag. Is there any way to prevent this

Would this have anything to do with it being connected to Expo?

Comment: This shouldn't affect the app in release, only debug all the same.

Comment: But it is being affected with my released apps. I'm experiencing this with those also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by caching your assets while the app loading screen is still up: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets.html

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time seeing this. Will implement this in the morning :)

Comment: should I cache all the images used in the application? ( local images and images fetched from the internet ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found out it's an Expo thing. They strip all of the local images and put it in their cdn before building the app. Take note if you have an app in production using Expo